# How to find API hit count in Amazon AWS where my one of the API is configured in AWS\ApiGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have configured an existing HTTP GET API of Java application in AWS\ApiGateway.
The API has two queryParamters namely command and pageURL, command will be a constant(fixed value) so no worry on that but pageURL will be changed for different pages, so basically for my API different pages will be called with different pageURLs.

> So now I want to keep track on visit count for every page for that
> API, **API gateway cache** is enabled for my API so I can't write a logic in my Java
> application to keep a track on the same as not all calls will hit my
> application server.
>
> Please suggest a solution to me. I was exploring get-metric-data and
> get-metric-statistics of cloudWatch.  I am able to get the data-points
> (for the API) but couldn't able to figure out a way to find the
> data-points page wise which I want for every minute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **API dashboard in the API Gateway** Console to display the CloudWatch metrics of your deployed API in API Gateway.

1. Go to API gateway in the AWS console and choose your API.
2. choose Dashboard, it will display a summary of API activity over time, for Stage, choose the desired stage. **You can also use 'From' and 'To' to enter the date range.**

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for replying, but I am looking for more than that, the API dashboard will give me cumulative data for the API but I am more interested on page wise count for that API where page are defined as/by the query parameter values coming on that API call.

And I am looking for some Java API so that I can call that API only every minutes to get the hit of pages which hit by users.